# why debug statement show Id instead of name while test class execution?

Tags: class, debug

[image]

I run the test class and try to capture the permission set name in debug. But i got Id than name. Any reason why I am getting this ? Please help me to understand.

See the image, what i query in return what i got !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When debugging only the query results the relationships simply show the id.

If you want the name you have to explicitly debug `permissionset.name`